# Get dbpedia link of entity using stanford NER

Tags: nlp, sparql, stanford-nlp, dbpedia, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to find entities from text using `stanford NER`. It is working fine so far. Now I want to find the `dbpedia` link of the entities. 
I have seen it is available in `alchemy API`. 
Is it possible to find the `dbpedia` links of entities using stanford NER?

Comment: Sure you just need to write a SPARQL query to get the data out of DBpedia.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your NER extracts and then we can provide a link to DBpedia for you.

Answer (score 2):

Normally all the entities in Dbpedia have `rdfs:label` that is a string assigned to the entity. Therefore, when you are faced with a name extracted by your NER, you can use it for filtering purposes. The following example will provide he URI of all the entities that have label `Sulfuric acid`:

```
select distinct * 
    where {
    ?URI rdfs:label ?name.
    filter(str(?name)="Sulfuric acid")
}
```

However, labels are not always what you seek, you sometimes need to actually look for the `name` assigned to your URI. For example, if you open [sulfuric acid](http://dbpedia.org/page/Sulfuric_acid) page, you can see that it contains `dbpprop:iupacname`. As a result you need to change the query to:

```
select distinct * 
    where {
    ?URI dbpprop:iupacname ?name.
    filter(str(?name)="Sulfuric acid")
}
```

In this particular example the result sets are the same. But imagine you are tasked with finding `London` then you need to change your property to `foaf:name` and when running both the following queries, the result sets are quite different.

```
select distinct * 
    where {
    ?URI rdfs:label ?name.
    filter(str(?name)="London")
}
```

this contains 8 results while the following query contains 21 results.

```
    select distinct * 
    where {
    ?URI foaf:name ?name.
    filter(str(?name)="London")
}
```

So my point is that you need to decide if you want to use labels or names. And if you decide to use names, you need to find the appropriate property to write a SPARQL query. After that, you just need a method to access DBpedia with your query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stanford NER to extract the entity names and DBpedia Spotlight to link to the DBpedia URIs.